# How to get the User ~/Library path in Java for the Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, file, operating-system

On the Mac OS, from what I understand you're suppose to store information in "/Library/Application Support/Your App Name" if the files are to be read by everyone. However when it comes to writing, this is an admin only folder.

Therefore, if you want to write data, you need to store it to "~/Library/Application Support/Your App Name". Notice the "~" at the front. When you do this, each user will have their own data for the app, and be able to read and write.

In Java, if I do new File("~/Library"), this does not work as expected. It just adds "~/Library" to my current folder. Instead what I'd like it to do is return "Users/myAccount/Library". I understand that [it's suggested you store files there](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/Articles/WhereToPutFiles.html).

The question is how do I create a File object in Java to point to this folder?

Comment: The link that you say suggests not to store files in the ~/Library folder actually does nothing of the sort. That's where your program is supposed to store its files.

Comment: My mistake. I misread: "t is important to remember that the user domain (/Users) is intended for files created by the user. With the exception of the ~/Library directory, your application should never install files into the user’s home directory. In particular, you should never install files into a user’s Documents directory or into the /Users/Shared directory. These directories should only be modified by the user." I missed "with the exception of"... Thanks Rob for pointing it out!

Comment: Just fixed the question according to your comments Rob. Thanks again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Java, in its typical "why use one character when you can use forty" style, lets you access the `"~"` directory via `System.getProperty("user.home")`.