# Access a directory

Tags: java

I am using MacBook. I have a file located under `~/temp/note.txt`.

(`~` represents home directory by default in terminal).

I want to access this file in my java code:

```
File fileDir = new File("~/temp");
// I get exist = false, why?
boolean exist = fileDir.exist();
```

But my java code can't find the directory `~/temp`. I guess it is because java code can't recognize `~` ? How to make it work ?

Comment: Try ./ instead of ~/ if you are running this program from the home directory. If you want the home directory, you need to give the path explicitly

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the User ~/Library path in Java for the Mac OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095944/how-to-get-the-user-library-path-in-java-for-the-mac-os)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to find the users home directory in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585534/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-home-directory-in-java)

Comment: How nice would it be if people checked if a question and answer already existed before posting anything..

Comment: An information I am missing in the other answers: `~` is parsed by the shell. The issue that it doesn't work exists in all (other) programming languages.

Comment: Do you have a folder called `~`? No? That's why. (`~` is only a shortcut to save typing in your shell, it's not what the directory is actually called)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you could use the system variables and concatenate with 'temp.txt'.
You could obtain your user home directory via :

```
 System.getProperty("user.home")
```

If it's not ok, try

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

Hope this could help

Comment: `user.home` does the trick. Thanks, I need 8min to accept your answer.